# Change lookup regex in DRF Routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How can we change the ***lookup regex*** for the **`lookup_field`** in a viewset and router?

---

#### Conde Snippet

```
# serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff')


# views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
```

and if we try to access the ***detail-view*** as ***`/api/v1/users/foo@bar.com/`*** it's raising a 404

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The router will match lookup values containing any characters except slashes and period characters. For a more restrictive (or lenient) lookup pattern, set the **`lookup_value_regex`** attribute on the viewset. That is set the **`lookup_value_regex`** in the view class to match the **`lookup_field`**

```
# views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_value_regex = '[\w.@]+' # You can set any valid regex here to match anything excepts 'slashes'
```

**Source:** [**DRF Routers**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)